# Don't know what to use in this if-statement

Tags: python, if-statement, isnumeric, isalpha

```py
isr = input()
if (isr.isalpha() or (isr.isnumeric() and isr.isalpha())):
    print("You can't use a letter here.")              
else: 
    isr = math.sqrt(float(isr)) 
    print(isr)
```

So i wanted it to detect if the `isr` string gonna have a letter for example: "a" or a letter with a number "a8". I tried with the `and` and `or`logical operators, but with the actual code it just gives me "could not convert string to float: 'xxx'" like it kinda just skips the whole `if` line. When I put the "," instead of `and` then I put there a "a3" and it says the right thing it should say, but when i put there a normal number that You can actually use in the square rooting it says the thing that it shouldn't.

For `and` = "a3" the visual studio gonna say "could not convert string to float: 'a3'.
For `and` = "a" it gonna print the right thing "You can't use a letter here.".
For `and` = "4" it gonna print "2.0" as it should.

The one with the `,` instead of `and`.

```py
isr = input()
if (isr.isalpha() or (isr.isnumeric(), isr.isalpha())):
    print("You can't use a letter here.")              
else: 
    isr = math.sqrt(float(isr)) 
    print(isr)
```

For `,` = "a3" It prints out the right thing "You can't use a letter here."
For `,` = "a" It prints out the right thing "You can't use a letter here."
For `,` = "4" Should print the 2 but it prints out "You can't use a letter here."

Anyone can help me with it?

Comment: The `isnumeric()` method returns `True` if **all** the characters are numeric. The `isalpha()` method returns `True` if **all** the characters are alphabet letters (a-z). So, it's impossible for `(isr.isnumeric() and isr.isalpha())` to be `True`. The part with `isr.isalpha() or (isr.isnumeric(), isr.isalpha())` also makes no sense; the part to the right of the `or` will always be evaluated as `True` because it's a tuple of two values, and the truth value of a tuple with items in it is always `True`.

Answer (score 1):

The `isnumeric` and `isalpha` functions tell you if the *entire string* is numeric or alphabetic:

```
>>> "aa".isalpha()
True
>>> "aa3".isalpha()
False
```

Rather than trying to stack a bunch of conditions to tell you if a string is a valid `float` that you can take the square root of, just use `try/except`:

```
>>> isr = "a3"
>>> try:
...     print(math.sqrt(float(isr)))
... except ValueError:
...     print(f"{isr} isn't a valid number.")
...
a3 isn't a valid number.
```